# Reduce requests on production server for active storage files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rails-activestorage

I have about 100 small images on html page (avatars). Browser create 100 requests at same time, and nginx passenger return 503 with Request queue full (config limit).

If I add expires for images in nginx config after some time all images are 404, because active storage old links not working anymore.

How I can create permanent link to active storage image and cache with nginx expires?